# Matrix derivative of trace(AB) and ln(det(A)) with respect to a vector

Tags: determinant, matrix-calculus, trace

I am confused by myself on matrix derivation with respect to a vector. I
wish to get some help from all of you. Thanks in advance!

Both $A\left( \mathbf{\theta }%
\right) $ and $B\left( \mathbf{\theta }\right) $ are nonsingular square
matrices of a vector $\mathbf{\theta ,}$ I am looking for the following
matrix derivative:
$\frac{\partial tr\left(
A\left( \mathbf{\theta }\right) ^{-1}B\left( \mathbf{\theta }\right) \right)
}{\partial \mathbf{\theta }}.$

As an example, $A\left( \mathbf{\theta }%
\right) =\left( \mathbf{I}+\mathbf{\theta \theta }^{\prime }\right) $ where $%
\mathbf{I}$ is an identity matrix, and $B\left( \mathbf{\theta }\right)
=\left( \mathbf{C}+\mathbf{a\mathbf{\theta }^{\prime }+\theta b}^{\prime }+%
\mathbf{\theta \theta }^{\prime }\right) $ where $\mathbf{C}$ is a matrix
of constants, both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ are vectors of constants assuming the dimension matches. Is there any chain rule for the derivatives? Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the matrix derivative"? The natural way to present such a derivative is as an order $3$ tensor (i.e. as a $3$-dimensional array), but the details of how the entries are arranged depends on the specific tensor calculus conventions that you are using. Alternatively, if you don't know exactly what kind of "data type" you're looking for, it would be helpful if you could say what exactly it is that you are trying to do with this derivative

Comment: Or perhaps you would prefer to have the partial derivative of your function with respect to a particular entry of the vector $\theta$; this would naturally be presented as a matrix.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the $A(\theta),\,B(\theta)$ functions? Are they simple like $A=\theta\theta^T$ or $B={\rm Diag}(\theta),\,$ or more something more complicated?

Comment: I have added the form for $A$ and $B$. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Matrix Cookbook contains many useful formulas like the following
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\log(\det(X))}{\partial X} &= X^{-T} 
 \quad&\implies\quad&d\log(\det(X)) = X^{-T}:dX \\
\frac{\partial{\,\rm Tr}(X)}{\partial X} &= I
 \quad&\implies\quad&d{\,\rm Tr}(X) = I:dX \\
}$$
Substituting the given variables
$$\eqalign{
A &= I+\theta\theta^T
 \quad&\implies\quad
&dA = (d\theta\,\theta^T+\theta\,d\theta^T) \\
I &= A^{-1}A
 \quad&\implies\quad
&0 = dA^{-1}A + A^{-1}\,dA \\
&&&dA^{-1} = -A^{-1}dA\,A^{-1} \\
\\
(B-C) &= \theta\theta^T + a\theta^T + \theta b^T
 \quad&\implies\quad&dB = dA + a\,d\theta^T + d\theta\,b^T \\
\\
X &\doteq A^{-1}B
 \quad&\implies\quad&dX = A^{-1}dB + dA^{-1}B \\
}$$
yields
$$\eqalign{
d{\,\rm Tr}(X) &= I:dX \\
 &= I:(A^{-1}\,dB - A^{-1}dA\,A^{-1}B) \\
 &= A^{-T}:(dA+a\,d\theta^T + d\theta\,b^T) - A^{-T}B^TA^{-T}:dA \\
 &= A^{-T}:(a\,d\theta^T + d\theta\,b^T)
  +(A^{-T}-A^{-T}B^TA^{-T}):(d\theta\,\theta^T+\theta\,d\theta^T) \\
 &= \big(A^{-T}b + A^{-1}a\big):d\theta
  + \big(A^{-T}+A^{-1}-A^{-T}B^TA^{-T}-A^{-1}BA^{-1}\big)\theta:d\theta \\
\\
\frac{\partial{\rm Tr}(X)}{\partial\theta}
 &= A^{-T}b + A^{-1}a
  + \Big(A^{-T}+A^{-1}-A^{-T}B^TA^{-T}-A^{-1}BA^{-1}\Big)\theta \\
\\
}$$

---

In some of the steps above, a colon is used to denote
the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A
}$$
The properties of the trace under transposition and cyclic permutation of its argument, allows the terms in such a product to be rearranged in several equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= AC^T:B = B^TA:C &= \ldots \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T = I:A^TB &= \ldots \\
}$$

Comment: Hi Greg! I deeply appreciate for your effort on this. I am not a math major, and I am trying to follow your steps. My actual problem is a much complicated with the inverse of $A^{-1}$and I am confused again (sorry for my limited knowledge on matrix algebra). I will deeply deeply appreciate if you could help me on the revised question. Deeply appreciate for that!

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are my lifesaver! Can you recommend some books on this for self learning? I am not math/stat major, but occasionally I need to use matrix derivatives for my research. Thanks again!